# Facebook integration showing alert address is invalid

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am new in iPhone application development. Now i am developing application for iPhone  In this application I need to upload video to Facebook. i am used below code. Now enter Facebook the user name and password. **showing error message alert. like safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid.**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"Facebook_App_Id"];


                //@"com.facebook.samples.VideoUploadTest"];
    facebook.sessionDelegate = self;

}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSArray* permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"publish_stream", nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
    [permissions release];
}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   videoData, @"video.mov",
                                   @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                   @"Video Test Title", @"title",
                                   @"Video Test Description", @"description",
                                   nil];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
}
```

referred from this url [[http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/532/]](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/532/)

Comment: Did you remember to set up the iOS SSO settings correctly? if not, the facebook app won't be able to link back to your app after login

Comment: sorry. i am not did that. how to set iOS SSO settings. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this for SSO settings.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/